# Can't get std::array's data() method to work as a constexpr, am I doing something silly?

Tags: c++, arrays, std

So, according to CPP reference, I should be able to use `data()` as a constexpr. My minimal example is as such:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc,char** argv){
    using Container_t = std::array<double, 10>;

    constexpr Container_t arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    constexpr const double* data = arr.data();

    return arr[0];
}
```

And [here is the compile error](https://godbolt.org/z/3P7MqjGhn) that comes out of this code. I see a similar error on all major compilers, so I must be missing something about what the specification allows, but this seems like a simple case. Thanks!

Comment: [You did not enable C++17 compilation](https://godbolt.org/z/K6cdhGMnb)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hmm, I'm not sure why that compiles. I'm definitely using C++20 flags on my local machine, and it doesn't, nor does it compile using Clang with C++20 flags. https://godbolt.org/z/6exGoz83a

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie To follow up, it fails if you switch to a more recent version of MSVC

Comment: Side note: `constexpr` implies `const`. So `constexpr const ...` is redundant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl *"So `constexpr const ...` is redundant"* -- Not always. It is redundant in the declaration `constexpr const double data`, which declares that `data` is both `constexpr` and `const`. However, it is not redundant in `constexpr const double* data`, which declares that `data` is `constexpr` and `*data` is `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `constexpr` pointer *must* point to something with static storage duration.

Your `arr` doesn't have a fixed address since it is a local variable, so `arr.data()` can't be a constant expression.

It can be used as *part* of a constant expression:

```cpp
constexpr Container_t arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
static_assert(arr.data()[2] == 3.0);
static_assert(arr.data() + 3 == &arr[3]);
```

If you want it to be a constant expression, make `arr` have static storage duration:

```cpp
static constexpr Container_t arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
constexpr const double* data = arr.data();
```

Comment: Thanks @artyer, that makes sense, and answers my original question. Do you recommend any workarounds if I don't desire static duration of the object?

Comment: @Danny Local `constexpr` arrays usually act like they copy from an unnamed static storage duration object, so there is usually no downside to just adding `static` to get rid of the middleman. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/jx1v7Wz1P . If you are in a constexpr function before C++23 (where you can't use `static constexpr`), make the local variable a global variable. You can also work with an index into the data instead (Instead of having `constexpr const double* data = arr.data() + n` and `*data`, have `constexpr std::size_t index = n;` and use `data[n]`).

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up opting for the latter approach, and prototyped out something that gets me what I want without the static storage duration.